# Show most repeated columns first in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Thanks in advance.
I want to show the columns with most repeated values first like this

```
col1    col2
1        A
1        B
1        C
1        D
2        A
2        B
2        C
4        D
4        E
3        A
```

In 'col1' since '1' is repeated four times it should come first and '2' repeated thrice it comes second.
need to write sql query to get this result.
Please help me.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose you this solution :

```
WITH temp AS (
  SELECT col1, count(col2) nb_occurences
  FROM tab
  GROUP BY
    col1)


SELECT
  tab.col1, tab.col2, nb_occurences
FROM tab
INNER JOIN
  temp
    ON temp.col1 = tab.col1
ORDER BY nb_occurences DESC
```

I hope this will help you :)

Good Luck

Comment: I have to show both the columns. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming SQL Server 2005 or newer you can make use of the `OVER()` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  Table1
ORDER BY COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY col1) DESC
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/82a2b/3/0)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   col1
FROM     (SELECT   col1, COUNT(*) AS cnt
          FROM     my_table
          GROUP BY col1) t
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```